# Nginx not starting up

Tags: nginx

I have a custom build of tengine, which is a fork of nginx. I built it with the options
`--prefix=/home/gaurav/projects/tengine_custom/BUILD --add-module=/home/gaurav/projects/tengine_custom/nginx-rtmp-module --with-jemalloc --without-http_fastcgi_module --without-http_uwsgi_module --without-http_scgi_module`

`nginx -V` ouputs the following:

```
Tengine version: Tengine/2.3.2
nginx version: nginx/1.17.3
built by gcc 9.3.0 (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
```

Running the binary results in the following:

`nginx: [emerg] invalid IPv6 address in resolver "[fe80::1%wlo1]" in /home/gaurav/projects/tengine_custom/BUILD/conf/nginx.conf:137`

I tried googling but turned up nothing. Can somebody help me with this?

Config file: https://pastebin.com/yUtrcwUF

Comment: Can you show line 137 of nginx.conf file ?

Comment: It is just a curly brace.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan, I just linked my config file.

Answer (score 0):

Add `--with-ipv6` to your build options.

Comment: Tried already got `./configure: warning: the "--with-ipv6" option is deprecated`. Still the same error.

Comment: @GauravJoseph does your `/etc/resolv.conf` contains `IPV6`? Try to disable the line.